# Inverse prediction function

Tags: numerical-value

I am trying to write a code which learns a data set. Now, I want to know the input value for a given output value. Consider, the following code

```
trainset = {{1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6}}
fn = Predict[trainset]
```

Now I want to solve for m

```
Solve[fn[m] == 5, m]
```

Is there any way to find value of `m`, other than plotting the function looking for the input value which gives `5`.

Comment: Your training should be a list of rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
trainset = Rule@@@{{1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6}}
fn = Predict[trainset];
```

First get the predictor function using `PredictorInformation`:

```
PredictorInformation[fn,"Function"]
(* 0.0000199999 + 1.99999 #1 & *)
```

Then invert it using `InverseFunction`:

```
fnInv=InverseFunction[PredictorInformation[fn,"Function"]]
(* 0.500003 (-0.0000199999 + 1. #1) & *)

fn[3]
(* 5.99999 *)
fnInv[%]
(* 3. *)
```

Note: Unfortunately, this approach works only when `Method` is `"LinearRegression"`; it does not work for `Method`s `"RandomForest"` and `"NearestNeighbors"` as they do not have the `"Function"` property.

Comment: Thanks kguler. This uses the Linear regression method. What if the method used is "NearestNeighbors", then can we find the inverse function ??
Consider the following code. In this "NearestNeighbors" method is used.


x1 = Range[0, 0.1, .001];
x2 = x1^2;
trainset = Rule @@@ Transpose[{x1, x2}];
fn= Predict[trainset]

Comment: @Anjan, unfortunately this approach works only when `Method` is `"LinearRegression"`; it does not work for `Method`s `"RandomForest"` and `"NearestNeighbors"` as they do not have the `"Function"` property.